# How to get back value present in button on mouseclick event

Tags: javascript

Currently I am getting a huge object when I'm logging `x`.

How to get the value from the event?

```
   function IncrementOnClick() {
     function increment(x) {
       console.log(x);
     }
   
     return (
       <div>
         <button onClick={increment}>1</button>
       </div>
     );
   }
```

Comment: That big object is the `event` object The element is `x.target`. If a `value` existed on the element it would be `x.target.value`. There is no value on that button though

Answer (score 1):

It would seem you are using reactJs rather then pure JavaScript.

By calling `onClick={increment}` the parameter you pass to `increment` is an event. To get the target that you clicked on use `x.target`, and if you want the targets value `x.target.value`. for example:

```
  const increment = ({ target }) => console.log(target.value);

  return (
    <div>
      <button value="submit" onClick={increment}>
        Manikanta
      </button>
    </div>
  );
```

EDIT

Since you wish the get the inner text `Manikanta` rather then the actual value, use `target.innerText`. So in this case would be:

```
  const increment = ({ target }) => console.log(target.innerText);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={increment}>Manikanta</button>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: this is not logging anything

Comment: Make sure to give your <button> a `value="some value here"` as showed in my code, @mani_thelearner . You cant log a value if it does not exist

Comment: My question::: how do I get back Manikanta...adding value="some value here" did not work

Comment: So you wish to get not a value of the button but the text inside the <button> element. Your title is a little bit misleading

Comment: @mani_thelearner I edited the code in my answer to output the inner text of   `Manikanta` rather then the value, as you requested. Hope this solves it

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using React seeing your return statement and the curly braces JS blocks in the JSX. You can do something like the following:

```js
import React, {useState} from "react";

function IncrementOnClick() {
  // Setup the state to store the clicks 
  const [clicks, setClicks] = useState(0);
  // You can learn more about hooks here: 
  // https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html


  function increment(e) {
    // The argument `e` that you get to the function is the click 
    // event, which can be used to get a lot of information about 
    // the click like the coordinates of the click, button's information
    // and a lot more other information.  

    // every time the button is clicked, you add 1 to the clicks.
    setClicks((prevClicks) => prevClicks + 1);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={increment}>Clicks = {clicks}</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: In plain JS.... I wanted to know the relation between event and prevClicks

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite understand what you wanted to return but if I understood correctly this is the right code

```js
 function increment(x) {
      console.log(x);

      return x;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    
</head>
<div>
    <button onClick="increment(20);">Manikanta</button>
  </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```